# tcpClient and IRC client issues

Tags: c#, tcpclient, irc

Can someone tell me why the following code isn't working?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TCPClient {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        private TcpClient client;
        private Thread readThread;
        private NetworkStream stream;
        private Stream dataStream;
        private Encoding dataStreamEncoding;
        private StreamWriter writer;
        private StreamReader reader;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.client = new TcpClient();
            this.readThread = new Thread(ReadLoop);
            this.dataStreamEncoding = Encoding.Default;

            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
            this.readThread.Name = "ReadThread";
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (this.client != null && !this.client.Connected) {


                try {
                    this.client.Connect("open.ircnet.net", 6666);

                    if (this.client != null && this.client.Connected) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                    }

                    // Set up network I/O objects.
                    this.stream = this.client.GetStream();
                    this.writer = new StreamWriter(this.stream, this.dataStreamEncoding);
                    this.reader = new StreamReader(this.stream, this.dataStreamEncoding);

                    //HandleClientConnected(state.Item3);
                    this.readThread.Start();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping Sent");
            this.writer.Write("PING");
            this.writer.Flush();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Login Info Sent");
            this.writer.Write(  "PASS *\r\n" + 
                                "NICK testing3134\r\n" + 
                                "USER guest 8 * :\"John Doe\"");
            this.writer.Flush();
        }

        private void ReadLoop() {
            try {
                // Read each message from network stream, one per line, until client is disconnected.
                while (this.client != null && this.client.Connected) {
                    var line = this.reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null)
                        break;

                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }

                if(!this.client.Connected) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Connected
:ircnet.eversible.com 020 * :Please wait while we process your connection to ircnet.eversible.com
Login Info Sent
Ping Sent
The thread 'ReadThread' (0x10bc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
ERROR :Closing Link: testing3134[unknown@24.255.34.216] (Ping timeout)
```

Changes that made it work:

**Original:**

```
    private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping Sent");
        this.writer.Write("PING");
        this.writer.Flush();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Info Sent");
        this.writer.Write(  "PASS *\r\n" + 
                            "NICK testing3134\r\n" + 
                            "USER guest 8 * :\"John Doe\"");
        this.writer.Flush();
    }
```

**WORKING:**

```
    private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Ping Sent");
        this.writer.WriteLine("PING\r\n");
        this.writer.Flush();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Login Info Sent");
        this.writer.WriteLine("PASS *\r\n");
        this.writer.Flush();
        this.writer.WriteLine("NICK testing3134\r\n");
        this.writer.Flush();
        this.writer.WriteLine("USER guest 8 * :\"John Doe\"\r\n");
        this.writer.Flush();
    }
```

Not only did I switch from `Write` to `WriteLine` but like the accepted answer suggests I add line returns to the end of all the requests being sent.

Comment: Are you meant to pass a new-line at the end of the IRC commands? You don't at the end of either your PING or USER.

Comment: I'm not sure if the new line is necessary in order to send the command. I believe it's just `writer.Write()`

Comment: I suggest you find out for certain. It would be quite odd not to have a new line, as otherwise the server can't easily tell when you've finished a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not including a line break after the PING or USER messages.

From [RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-2.3):

> IRC messages are always lines of characters terminated with a CR-LF (Carriage Return - Line Feed) pair

So you should have:

```
this.writer.Write("PASS *\r\n" + 
                  "NICK testing3134\r\n" + 
                  "USER guest 8 * :\"John Doe\"\r\n");
```

and:

```
this.writer.Write("PING\r\n");
```

I'd also avoid using `Encoding.Default` if I were you. The RFC specifies that no particular character encoding is used, but it *does* expect it to be an 8-bit one (rather than potentially multi-byte). This is a poor way of specifying an encoding, but I'd probably use either ASCII or ISO-8859-1 explicitly.

Comment: No change. Same result, not getting any return messages from the server.

Comment: At that point, I suggest you use Wireshark to see what's going on in terms of traffic then - watch what happens with a real client, and what happens with your code.

Comment: YOU ARE A GODDDD!!! Thank you for all your suggestions ESP the wireshark thing. I was wondering if it was the tcpClient messing up and not capturing responses, but I got it working. I'll edit my original post to reflect the changes I made! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Rawr: You shouldn't need WriteLine as well as putting the line break in explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

SOmething else to consider here is that most irc servers send you a "ping cookie" when you connect. This consists of a PING message with a random string as its parameter. You MUST respond to this with a PONG containing the same random string, or your connection will be terminated with a "Ping Timeout" message. This is a simple method of preventing fire-and-forget use of irc through proxies, and is very common.

You should add functionality to work with this into your client.